# How to avoid for loop in spark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've a use case as below in PySpark:

```
df.show()
emp_no dept_no emp_name emp_address location
 1.     10.     ABC.     AAA.         X
 2.     20.     DEF.     CCC.         Y
 3.     20.     GHI.     DDD.         Z
 4.     10.     JKL.     EEE.         Y
```

And, I've below 2 lists:

```
dept_list = [10, 20]
location_list = ['Y', 'Z']
```

now i'm iterating lists for data-frame and doing joining as below:

```
lst = []
for a, b in zip(dept_list, location_list):
  df1 = df.where(col('dept_no' == a))
  df2 = df.where(col('location' == b))
  join_conditions = [df1.dept_no==df2.dept_no, df1.emp_address==df2.emp_address]
  result_df = df1.join(df2, join_conditions, how="inner").select(df1.emp_id, df1.emp_name)
  lst.append(result_df)
```

Finally doing union of all as below:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
final_df = reduce(DataFrame.union, lst)
```

Now final result:

```
final_df.show()
emp_no emp_name
  4.   JKL
  3.   GHI
```

How can I avoid this FOR loop ?

**EDIT1:**
if we have similar lists for same column [i.e., location] then how to use ?
For example:

```
location_list_1 = ['X', 'Y']
location_list_2 = ['Z', 'Z'] # value can be repeated here, but len(location_list_1)=len(location_list_2)

lst = []
for a, b in zip(location_list_1, location_list_2):
  df1 = df.where(col('location' == a))
  df2 = df.where(col('location' == b))
  join_conditions = [df1.dept_no==df2.dept_no, df1.emp_address==df2.emp_address]
  result_df = df1.join(df2, join_conditions, how="fullouter").select(nvl(df1.emp_id, df2.emp_id), nvl(df1.emp_name, df2.emp_name))
  lst.append(result_df)
```

And output should be:

```
emp_no emp_name
  1.   ABC  # from 1st iteration in FOR loop [for location 'X' & 'Z']
  3.   GHI  # from 1st iteration in FOR loop [for location 'X' & 'Z']
  2.   DEF  # from 2nd iteration in FOR loop [for location 'Y' & 'Z']
  4.   JKL  # from 2nd iteration in FOR loop [for location 'Y' & 'Z']
  3.   GHI  # from 2nd iteration in FOR loop [for location 'Y' & 'Z']

# Here, 3-GHI should come twice.
```

Here similarly, how to avoid FOR loop ?

Comment: What's the result you want in the end?

Comment: Do you need a single dataframe in the output? Like the union of the dataframes in `lst`?

Comment: Yes, finally I'm doing union of all df from the lst. I've updated the code for this union.

Comment: @rchome
even if i don't get "final_df", that's also fine, as I can to push to parquet the "result_df" directly instead of union of all DFs.

Comment: @TempExpt what's the join condition? could you show an example of what the `final_df` looks like at the end?

Comment: @rchome
I've updated for final result.

Comment: can you give some details about the data? what are the relationships between columns (one-to-one, many-to-many etc.)?

Comment: @rudolfovic
this is just sample data, not the actual one.
Basic requirement is, i need to iterate 2 lists and get data from same DF, then join those 2 DFs based on conditions, and push back the result to parquet.
The overall functionality is working fine me. But as these 2 lists are having 100+ elements each and the base DF is having millions of rows, which is causing slowness of performance.

Answer (score 1):

If `emp_address` is not unique then perform a self-join on it (`df.join(df, 'emp_address')`) and then filter using the following condition: `(dept_no, location) in zip(dept_list, location_list)`.

The easiest way to do this would be to create a tiny UDF:

```
def check(x, y):
  return (x,y) in zip(list1, list2)

f = udf(check, StringType(), IntegerType())
df.filter(f(col(x), col(y))
```

Alternatively, you can concatenate the two columns as strings (using some separator) - then you can use `isin`:

```
my_list = [f'{x}:::{y}' for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
df.filter(concatenate(col(x), lit(':::'), col(y)).isin(my_list))
```

You may need to pass some parameters like `r_suffix` to the join since you have the same column names on both sides of the join.

If your joins are anything but inner, you need to join first before filtering. Otherwise, filter first so you have fewer rows to join.

Comment: No, emp_address is being used in join condition which is NOT unique.

Comment: Answer adjusted accordingly

Comment: Can you please share the sample UDF for this ?

Comment: will this work if I've similar lists using `fullouter` join? I've updated the question at "EDIT1".

Comment: if you filter first, the code is much more efficient but it will only give you the expected results for inner joins. if you join first the code will work no matter what but will not be as efficient as the first version (for inner joins). not sure if there is anything you could do to speed it up for outer joins so maybe this is as good as it gets

Comment: if I apply `join` then `filter`, again it'll be sequential processing. isn't it ?
any suggestion here how to optimise ?

Comment: not sure what you mean by sequential processing - spark is smart: towards the end of the join, if there are cores available to start filtering, it will

Comment: Can you pls share any sample for this what are you suggesting, that is `join` then `filter`. Do i need to do in loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import __or__
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

final_df = df.alias("a").join(
  df.alias("b"),
  on=reduce(
    __or__,
    [
      (f.col("a.dept_no") == f.lit(a)) & (f.col("b.location") == f.lit(b))
      for a, b in zip(dept_list, location_list)
    ]
  ) & (
    f.col("a.dept_no") == f.col("b.dept_no")
  ) & (
    f.col("a.emp_address") == f.col("b.emp_address")
  )
).select("a.emp_id", "b.emp_name")
```

Comment: not sure the reduce part can be included in the on - I think you might need to move it to a where clause since it merely filters

Comment: @rudolfovic filters can be included in the `on` part of the join no problem. Any boolean column can be

Comment: somehow the count isn't matching with this `reduce` if apply `fullouter` join. will this work if I've similar lists ? I've updated the question at "EDIT1".

Comment: that's right - because filtering on join only works with "inner"

Comment: but if you use "where" instead it should work (same logic as in my answer - in fact, it's the same solution pretty much, just one is more functional and the other more sql-like)

Comment: @rudolfovic
Yes I understood both the logics those you and @Arseny provided, but somehow in case of `fullouter` join, i got messed up as count not matching...